# Using Authjs database adapter in CredentialsProvider authorize() function

Tags: reactjs, next-auth, next.js14

Authjs provides a database adapter to connect to a database. There appear to be functions to retrieve information about the user such as:

[getUserByEmail](https://authjs.dev/reference/core/adapters#getuserbyemail)

But it is not clear how to use these functions. Are we able to use these in the
async authorize() function, that we define in CredentialsProvider(), to get the user from the database. Or, do we have to create our own functions to connect to the database.

Note that I am only interested in using the jwt session strategy and not Database session strategy.